# XML libraries for java

Tags: open-source, java, api, text-processing, xml

Please succintly summarize the licensing and vendor [implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54000005/262852) available for:

[XQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery_API_for_Java)
[JAXP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Processing)
[XQJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery_API_for_Java)

specific to Java and where the libraries can be found for build files.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't got time to do the question justice, but the main products you want to be looking at are probably

- BaseX (XQuery, XML database)
- eXist (XQuery, XML database)
- MarkLogic (XQuery and XSLT, XML database)
- Saxon (XSLT and XQuery, no database)
- Xalan (XSLT, no database)